# Next.js после деплоя на гитхаб pages выдает 404

Tags: развертывание, nextjs, github-pages

Всем привет, это мой первый проект на нексте. Гугл облазил, ответа не нашел
В режиме разработки сайт работает как часы, а вот после деплоя почему-то выдает 404 сходу. Помогите разобраться. Роутинг используется App

gh-pages: https://github.com/DenisGradov/MyFirstShop-next.js-ts/tree/gh-pages

github: https://github.com/DenisGradov/MyFirstShop-next.js-ts
[image: 404]
[image: сайт в режиме разработки]